# What Is the Logic Behind Advanced Indexing in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

When the following lines of codes are run, same results are expected. Is the logic behind advanced indexing in Numpy literally zipping different iterables together? If so, I am also curious about what data structure is converted into after zipping. I am using a tuple in my example, but it seems like there are other possibilities. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print(a[[0,1],[1,1]])
>>> [2 4]
result = zip([0,1],[1,1])
print(a[tuple(result)])
>>> [2 4]
```

Comment: For 1d lists like this this `zip` does the same thing (though the `numpy` code is compiled).  More generally `numpy` broadcasts the arrays against each other.  Thus indexing with a (2,1) and a (3,) yields a (2,3) selection.  Soon or later you need to study https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: On further thought your `zip` isn't right.  `((0,1),(1,1))` doesn't change anything.  `[[a[i,j] for i,j in result]` is closer.

Comment: Thank you for your response @hpaulj , I think your second thought is on point. It doesn't matter if I do `a[(1,2), (3,4)]` or `a[[1,2],[3,4]]`, I am getting the same results which are `a[1,3]` and `a[2,4]`. I also find the numpy doc a bit challenging to understand. On the other hand, I find this reference pretty helpful: [link] (https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/BasicIndexing.html)

Answer (score -1):

The list and tuple are basically the same - both hold items, but while `list` is mutable (i.e., you can change its elements) the latter is immutable.
But as far as the `numpy` indexing is concerned - you can use both, as long as they hold `integer` values.

The only advantage in using `tuple` for indexing is that it can not be changed in the middle, and mess up the data extraction (as shown in Example 1), if that is one of your requirements.

**Example 1 (imutable):**

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 6).reshape((2, 3))
idx = tuple(np.random.randint(0, 2, 10).reshape((5, 2)))
for i in range(3):
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    print(arr[idx])
```

**Output of Example 1:**

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

On the other hand, if you desire a more flexible indexing (as in Example 2), i.e., changing the indices in the process of the run - `tuples` won't work for you.

**Example 2 (Mutable):**

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 6).reshape((2, 3))
idx = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10).reshape((5, 2))
for i in range(3):
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    print(arr[idx])
```

**Output of Example 2:**

```
[[[0 6 8]
  [0 5 5]]

 [[0 5 5]
  [0 5 5]]

 [[0 6 8]
  [0 5 5]]...
```

So, whether to use one or another depends on the outcome you desire.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is what he was trying to do.  In numpy indexing tuple and list are different, e.g. `x[1,2], x[(1,2)], x[[1,2]]`.  He was using the tuple(zip()) to do a list 'transpose', and generate `i,j` pairs.